# "Dining Boarders" : Promise with a long-running 'then' function

Tags: design-patterns, asynchronous, promise

As a newbie trying to learn the concept of Promises and Futures, I have been amazed by the apparent simplicity of these concepts in asynchronous computations. While trying to write a really long chains of 'then's, I was thinking of this scenario, I am calling it **Dining Boarders Situation**.

Suppose, we have a promise `wakeUpBoarders`, after which a function `serveBreakfast` function should be called. Somehow the breakfasts take a long time to be prepared, so the boarders make the menu choices during supper. When breakfasts are served, the boarders eat them all. Eating meals is a fast operation, making meals is not. When boarders have finished eating, there will be another function named `orderForDinner` which will take boarders' order, and after a LONG RUNNING TIME, it will resolve a value during dinner.

Now, I could break the `orderForDinner` into two promises, the first one merely acknowledges having received the order, the second one actually runs in the background. But

- This second promise must actually succeed. Even if this second callback fails, it should be relaunched so that it is completed with a satisfactory output before dinner.
- This second phase of execution requires some "business secrets", which should be implemented only in kitchens. So, the `orderForDinner` should be designed in a way, which returns a quick response to the user, and resumes its long running background task with high guarantee of success.

Which could be a viable way to solve this problem using Promises? A working code demo would be really nice.
Does this design has a name, is it a design pattern?

Comment: The first one is just "retry", it's pretty easy to implement. For the first one - I think you'll find this interesting: http://www.erights.org/talks/thesis/markm-thesis.pdf

Comment: I was expecting a concise reply, but the topic of this thesis is interesting. Will definitely read it through during this weekend.
And I haven't found any code snippet requiring "retry" before. At least not in Javascript, where I am coding currently. I'll look into this. Thanks a lot for a head start.

Comment: `let retry = (fn, retries = 3) => fn().catch(e => retries > 0 ? retry(fn, retries - 1) : Promise.reject(e))` or something like that.

Comment: I agree, "a working code demo would be really nice" ... to help understand the question!

Comment: It rather sounds like you are seeking to implement some sort of [Workflow Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_pattern). As you will see, it's a rather large topic.